# Determine Genuine Windows Installation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

If I wanted to determine if a  user had a genuine copy of windows, how could I do that in C#? Can I integrate with [Windows Genuine Advantage](http://www.microsoft.com/genuine/AboutNotifications.aspx)?

Comment: Just curious - why would you want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

When I answered this question, I was answering in the context of the asker's language (C#). As another answerer pointed out, there is a way to do this in other languages, but it's platform dependent (Vista and above, from what I can see).

#### Old answer (Clarified)

As far as I know, there is no API documentation available for WGA (still true), and since hackers could conceivably (and have) break WGA by knowing its internals, I doubt Microsoft is going to open up an API for WGA.

Microsoft has a separate API for C++ and COM developement as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552392/determine-genuine-windows-installation-in-c/1552434#1552434) points out, but nothing available in the .NET Framework that I can see.

Realistically, there's no good reason to find this out. It's not the business of the program to know if the OS is legally installed.

#### Edit

Leaving my answer up since I cannot delete it; but if you want to use `Win32 API` and don't have to stay inside the .NET Framework, I suggest using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552392/determine-genuine-windows-installation-in-c/1552434#1552434).

Comment: Thank you George, I didnt think of it that way... Although it would be nice to know that some pirate isnt using your software on a pirated system, and who knows, they may be pirating your software as well...

Comment: -1, RRUZ's response shows that there is in fact a documented API for checking the validity status of a Windows installation.

Comment: For C#, it appears there is no way to; that was his question. I didn't mean a blanket 'for all languages'; and I ought to edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: George see the C# implementation wich added

Answer (score 20):

You can use [SLIsGenuineLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965837%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Checks whether the specified application is a genuine Windows installation), The Minimum supported client is Windows Vista.

[The Software Licensing API](http://207.46.16.251/en-us/library/cc296101%28VS.85%29.aspx) , The Software Licensing API (SLAPI) can be used to determine a genuine Microsoft Windows installation, install and log an asset management license, and retrieve information about the licensing policy of a software component.

**UPDATE**, I Wrote this basic C# implementation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
  using SLID = Guid; //SLID id declarated as typedef GUID SLID; in slpublic.h 

  class Program
  {

    public enum SL_GENUINE_STATE
    {
      SL_GEN_STATE_IS_GENUINE       = 0,
      SL_GEN_STATE_INVALID_LICENSE  = 1,
      SL_GEN_STATE_TAMPERED         = 2,
      SL_GEN_STATE_OFFLINE          = 3,
      SL_GEN_STATE_LAST             = 4
    }

    [DllImportAttribute("Slwga.dll", EntryPoint = "SLIsGenuineLocal", CharSet = CharSet.None, ExactSpelling = false, SetLastError = false, PreserveSig = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = false)]
    [PreserveSigAttribute()]
    internal static extern uint SLIsGenuineLocal(ref SLID slid, [In, Out] ref SL_GENUINE_STATE genuineState, IntPtr val3);


    public static bool IsGenuineWindows()
    {
        bool _IsGenuineWindows   = false;
        Guid ApplicationID       = new Guid("55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f"); //Application ID GUID http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772270.aspx
        SLID windowsSlid = (Guid)ApplicationID;  
        try
        {
          SL_GENUINE_STATE genuineState = SL_GENUINE_STATE.SL_GEN_STATE_LAST;
          uint ResultInt                = SLIsGenuineLocal(ref windowsSlid, ref genuineState, IntPtr.Zero);
          if (ResultInt == 0)
          {
            _IsGenuineWindows = (genuineState == SL_GENUINE_STATE.SL_GEN_STATE_IS_GENUINE);
          }
          else
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Error getting information {0}", ResultInt.ToString());          
          }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return _IsGenuineWindows;
    }    

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) //Version 6 can be Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, or Windows 7
      {
        if (IsGenuineWindows())
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Original Windows");        
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Not Original Windows");                
        }
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("OS Not supoprted");     
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. Where did `55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f` come from?

Comment: @BillyONeal this Windows APPID is part of the Volume Licensing feature introduced in Windows Vista, you can find more information here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772269.aspx

Comment: @RRUZ: That GUID doesn't appear to exist in that document. (I checked before asking)

Comment: @BillyONeal, this value is present in the [`Slmgr.vbs`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793433.aspx) file which is the `Windows Software Licensing Management Tool` , this script is located in the `c:\windows\system32` folder, now inside of that file check the `WindowsAppId` constant :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.